# Which is the command to run docopt in Rust

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, docopt

I am struggeling to find out which is the command to run a simple example of `docopt` but always I get the wrong result.

```rust
#[macro_use]
extern crate serde_derive;

use docopt::Docopt;

// Write the Docopt usage string.
const USAGE: &'static str = "
Usage: cp [-a] <source> <dest>
       cp [-a] <source>... <dir>
       tk [-a] <source> <dest>

Options:
    -a, --archive  Copy everything.
";

#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
struct Args {
    arg_source: String,
    arg_dest: String,
    arg_dir: String,
    flag_archive: bool,
}

fn main() {
    //let version = env!("CARGO_PKG_NAME").to_string() + ", version: " + env!("CARGO_PKG_VERSION");
    let args: Args = Docopt::new(USAGE)
        .and_then(|d| {
            println!("{:?}", d);
            d.deserialize()
        })
        .unwrap_or_else(|e| {
            println!("Error");
            e.exit()
        });

    println!("{:?}", args);
}
```

For example if I run that command in the CLI `cargo run -- cp -a file_a dest_a` the argument struct is not correct one

```rust
Args { arg_source: "", arg_dest: "", arg_dir: "des", flag_archive: true }
```

##### V2:

Now with that new implementation and adding the binary name to the commands, still not finding the right way to get the commands:

```
const USAGE: &'static str = "
Usage: 
    terminal --arch ARCHIVE --dest DESTIN

Options:
    --arch, -a  The file that you want to copy
    --dest, -d  Where you want to copy the file
";

#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
struct Args {
    flag_arch: Option<String>,
    flag_dest: Option<String>,
}
```

The following commands I am running

```
cargo run -- terminal --arch muun --dest hello
// Args { flag_arch: Some(""), flag_dest: Some("") }
cargo run -- terminal --arch muun --dest hello 
// Error
```

Comment: `cp` in the USAGE description is the binary itself, it's not supposed to be passed in. I would also assume the `tk` confuses docopt. Plus `arg_source` is of the wrong type, it needs to be some sort of sequence to support `...`

Comment: Also docopt is abandoned, both docopt.rs (which isn't super suitable to the language in the first place) and the original docopt.

Comment: the reason that I am using this because I saw in `rustls` crate and in its examples of `tlsserver-mio.rs`. Why is it wrong the arg_source type? Do you have any other option if that implementation is abandoned?

Comment: "Why is it wrong the arg_source type?" If you look at the original example in the docopt documentation, it's a Vec, since the ellipsis means it can receive multiple items.

Comment: "Do you have any other option if that implementation is abandoned?" It's not (just) the implementation which is abandoned it's the docopt concept itself. For declarative CLIs `clap`'s declarative API (formerly structopt) is probably the most common. But [there's a bunch](https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/rn3jt0/what_is_the_current_proper_way_to_get_command/) depending on your needs and wants.

Comment: If I interpret 'V3' corretly you solved your problem, you should add any solutions you found as answers, not in the question by editing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After few iterations and some help I got working the command line parser with `docopt` running the following command:
`cargo run -- --arch muun --dest hello`

```
#[macro_use]
extern crate serde_derive;

use docopt::Docopt;

// Write the Docopt usage string.
const USAGE: &'static str = "
Usage: 
    terminal --arch ARCHIVE --dest DESTIN 

Options:
    --arch ARCHIVE  The file that you want to copy
    --dest DESTIN  Where you want to copy the file
";

#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
struct Args {
    flag_arch: Option<String>,
    flag_dest: Option<String>,
}

fn main() {
    //let version = env!("CARGO_PKG_NAME").to_string() + ", version: " + env!("CARGO_PKG_VERSION");
    let args: Args = Docopt::new(USAGE)
        .and_then(|d| {
            println!("{:?}", d);
            d.deserialize()
        })
        .unwrap_or_else(|e| {
            println!("Error");
            println!("{:?}", e);
            e.exit()
        });

    println!("Archive: {:?}", args.flag_arch);
    println!("Destination: {:?}", args.flag_dest);
    println!("Args: {:?}", args);
}
```